# Updating phpunit from v5.1 to v6.5

Tags: php, phpunit, migration

I'm updating phpunit of one system from 5.1 to 6.5, but from the update, the tests that were all working successfully, began to fail.

The error is:

> 1) Tests\Administracao\Controller\AlunoControllerTest::testModuloController
>   TypeError: Argument 3 passed to SebastianBergmann\GlobalState\Snapshot::__construct() must be of the type boolean, null given, called in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php on line 2177

I looked for documentation of the migration but I didn't find it. Can anyone who has gone through this help me? Or do you know of any documents to carry out the migration?

The test code file in question is:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Administracao\Controller;

use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Domain\Model\Instituicao\Instituicao;
use Domain\Model\Usuario\Administrador;
use Domain\Model\Usuario\Email;
use Domain\Model\Usuario\Senha;


/**
 * Classe com métodos comuns para todos os controllers da api
 */
abstract class AbstractControllerTest extends TestCase
{   
    private $instituicao;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setApplicationConfig(include './config/application.config.php');
        parent::setUp();

        $serviceManager = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();

        $this->instituicao = $serviceManager->get('InstituicaoRepository')->getByUrl('uov');
    }

    public function auth()
    {
        // simula o repositório para não fazer modificações no banco
        $session = $this->getMock('Session', array('offsetGet', 'offsetUnset'));

        $usuario = $this->novoUsuario();

        $session->expects($this->any())
                ->method('offsetGet')
                ->willReturn($usuario);

        $serviceManager = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();
        $serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);
        $serviceManager->setService('Session', $session);
    }

    /**
     * Cria um novo usuário
     */
    private function novoUsuario()
    {
        $email = new Email('teste@email.com');
        $senha = new Senha('123456');       
        $usuario = new Administrador('Teste', $email, $senha, $this->instituicao);
        return $usuario;
    }
}
```

And also:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Administracao\Controller;

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

/**
 * Testa os métodos do controller do Aluno
 */
class AlunoControllerTest extends AbstractControllerTest
{
    public function testModuloController()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/uov/alunos');
        $this->assertModuleName('Administracao');
        $this->assertControllerName('Administracao\Controller\AlunoController');
        $this->assertControllerClass('AlunoController');
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('instituicao/alunos');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my version of ZendFramework(2.2.*) and the new version of phpUnit(6.5.*) aren't compatible. So I had to keep the previous one.